# Retrieving Multiple pages from a stock screener

Tags: python, pandas

I am scraping data from a stock screener. I am able to get the first page with the first 20 results using get_screener('111&r=1'). The next page would be get_screener('111&r=21') to get the next 20 results. I tried adding additional get requests but it gives me errors so I am not sure how to code this so it would give me additional rows.  Does anyone know how this would be done?

Thanks

```
 import requests 
    import pandas as pd
    
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    
    
    def get_screener(version):
        screen = requests.get(f'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v={version}&f=all', headers = headers).text
            
        tables = pd.read_html(screen)
        tables = tables[-2]
        tables.columns = tables.iloc[0]
        tables = tables[1:]
    
        return tables
    
    tables111 = get_screener('111&r=1')
    tables161 = get_screener('161&r=1')
    tables121 = get_screener('121&r=1')
    
    consolidatedtables = pd.merge(tables111,tables161,how='outer',left_on='Ticker',right_on='Ticker')
    consolidatedtables = pd.merge(consolidatedtables,tables121,how='outer',left_on='Ticker',right_on='Ticker')
    
    consolidatedtables.to_csv('test.csv')
    
    print(consolidatedtables)
```

New Code I'm using

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import bs4
import time
import random

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

def get_screener(version):
    url = 'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v={version}&r={page}&f=all'
    page = 1
   
    screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(screen.text, features='lxml')
    pages = int(soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'screener-pages'})[-1].text)
      
    data = []
    for page in range(1, 20 * pages, 20):
        print(version, page)
        screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers).text
        tables = pd.read_html(screen)
        tables = tables[-2]
        tables.columns = tables.iloc[0]
        tables = tables[1:]
        data.append(tables)
        time.sleep(random.random())
    return pd.concat(data).reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None)
       
df = get_screener('111')
df.info()

Output
111 1
111 21
111 41
111 61
111 81
111 101
111 121
111 141
111 161
111 181
111 201
111 221
111 241
111 8321
111 8341
111 8361
111 8381
111 8401
111 8421
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8439 entries, 0 to 8438
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------      --------------  ----- 
 0   No.         8439 non-null   object
 1   Ticker      8439 non-null   object
 2   Company     8439 non-null   object
 3   Sector      8439 non-null   object
 4   Industry    8439 non-null   object
 5   Country     8439 non-null   object
 6   Market Cap  8439 non-null   object
 7   P/E         8439 non-null   object
 8   Price       8439 non-null   object
 9   Change      8439 non-null   object
 10  Volume      8439 non-null   object
dtypes: object(11)
memory usage: 725.4+ KB
```

Comment: I tried with `'111&r61'` and other pages, that works perfectly. What is your problem?

Comment: My problem is I can only get 20 results. 111&r61d gives rows 61-80.  I want all the rows which are probably around 8,000.

Comment: Do a loop with `range(1, N, 20)`

Comment: Pretty much a novice here with loops so no idea how to implement that.  Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import bs4
import time
import random

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

def get_screener(version):
    url = 'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v={version}&r={page}&f=all'
    page = 1
   
    screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(screen.text)
    pages = int(soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'screener-pages'})[-1].text)
      
    data = []
    for page in range(1, 20 * pages, 20):
        print(version, page)
        screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers).text
        tables = pd.read_html(screen)
        tables = tables[-2]
        tables.columns = tables.iloc[0]
        tables = tables[1:]
        data.append(tables)
        time.sleep(random.random())
    return pd.concat(data).reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None)
       
df = get_screener('111')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       No. Ticker                           Company              Sector  ...    P/E   Price  Change   Volume
0        1      A        Agilent Technologies, Inc.          Healthcare  ...  39.97  157.80   0.65%  1409104
1        2     AA                 Alcoa Corporation     Basic Materials  ...  13.82   59.36   0.08%  7509699
2        3   AAAU   Goldman Sachs Physical Gold ETF           Financial  ...      -   17.99   0.33%   101432
3        4    AAC      Ares Acquisition Corporation           Financial  ...  43.53    9.75   0.00%    40324
4        5   AACG             ATA Creativity Global  Consumer Defensive  ...      -    1.24   1.64%    29131
...    ...    ...                               ...                 ...  ...    ...     ...     ...      ...
8434  8435    ZWS  Zurn Water Solutions Corporation           Utilities  ...  20.30   36.07   0.28%   461593
8435  8436     ZY                     Zymergen Inc.     Basic Materials  ...      -    7.61   4.10%   668322
8436  8437   ZYME                    Zymeworks Inc.          Healthcare  ...      -   16.57  -0.18%   269486
8437  8438   ZYNE     Zynerba Pharmaceuticals, Inc.          Healthcare  ...      -    3.23   0.62%   372210
8438  8439   ZYXI                       Zynex, Inc.          Healthcare  ...  39.00   10.96   3.69%   291003

[8439 rows x 11 columns]
```

**Update**

> Is it possible to get the other 2 screeners back that I had originally and merge the results?

Reuse your code:

```
tables111 = get_screener('111')
tables161 = get_screener('161')
tables121 = get_screener('121')
    
consolidatedtables = pd.merge(tables111,tables161,how='outer',left_on='Ticker',right_on='Ticker')
consolidatedtables = pd.merge(consolidatedtables,tables121,how='outer',left_on='Ticker',right_on='Ticker')
    
consolidatedtables.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: For some reason, I'm not getting the same result as you?                                      
        I get this error and I'm only getting the first 2 columns?                                                                                                 The code that caused this warning is on line 15 of the file C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\vince - Copy.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

Comment: So use `bs4.BeautifulSoup(screen.text, features='lxml')` and ensure `lxml` is installed (`pip install lxml`)

Comment: Hi, made that change and it runs but again, only the first 2 columns, no stock data. Using python 310 with lxml installed.
111 11
111 21
111 41
111 61
111 81

Comment: I don't understand why. I tried your 3 screeners and I get more than 8400 rows and 18 columns. Did you copy/paste my code in a file script and execute it?

Comment: In my original post, I put the code I received from you so you could see where I'm going wrong.  Thanks

Comment: I don't see where anything is being printed other than the version number and the page number?  Is it possible you didn't include more code at the bottom?  Thanks

Comment: `print(df)` <- did you try to display your dataframe?

Comment: I didn't see that line in the code you said to copy/paste.  I just tried putting that at the bottom and there was no change?

Comment: Update your post with the output of `df.info()` after `df = get_screener('111')`

Comment: I posted the output on my original post.  see the bottom, not running correctly.

Comment: The code ran perfectly. You have 8439 rows for your screener 111.

Comment: Did you see my output? It's not running for me though?

Comment: What do you want to do with this data? The variable `df` contains your data from the website.

Comment: I want to put it to a csv file so I ran work with the data in excel.

Comment: Try to: `df.to_csv('screener_111.csv')`. Do you have some data?

Comment: Yes, that worked!!  Is it possible to get the other 2 screeners back that I had originally and merge the results?  Thanks